# Создание 2D карты мира для глобальной стратегии UNITY

Tags: c#, unity3d

Не так давно я решился сделать игру-стратегию в unity и столкнулся с одной проблемой. Я не понимаю как красить карту и выделять границу особой линией. Допустим есть такая карта:

[image: Карта британии]

Я хочу по нажатии на провинции прекрашивать их в определенный цвет и перемещать линию границы (можно просто линию другого цвета). И желательно не через делёжку картинки на сотни спрайтов.
Буду очень благодарен если наведёте меня на верный путь по решению этой проблемы.

Comment: `Буду очень благодарен если наведёте меня на верный путь по решению этой проблемы.` - не надо такое писать, если наводка на верный путь вам на самом деле не нужна или не устраивает. Я понял, что вы пришли сюда не за подсказкой, а наверное за решением, поэтому удалил ответ как бесполезный. Собственно вы его и не приняли.

Comment: @aepot Я вам и слова не сказал про то, что меня что-то не устраивает, и решения у вас НИ РАЗУ не просил. А про бесполезность соглашусь.

Comment: Оффтоп вопрос. А как ты сделал карту мира с разделением на страны? Процедурная генерация?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не много подумав и покопавшись я решил эту проблему путём создания множества Polygon Colider 2D и его преобразование в MESH, а сам mesh легко красится через материал и вышел такой скрипт:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Source: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/trying-extrude-a-2d-polygon-to-create-a-mesh.102629/ </remarks>
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter), typeof(MeshRenderer), typeof(PolygonCollider2D))]
public class color : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Color extrudeColor = Color.white;
    public float frontDistance = -0.249f;
    public float backDistance = 0.249f;

    void Start()
    {
        PolygonCollider2D pol = GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();
        Mesh m = CreateMesh(pol.points, frontDistance, backDistance);

        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh = m;
        GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = extrudeColor;

        pol.isTrigger = true;
        pol.enabled = false;
    }

    private static Mesh CreateMesh(Vector2[] poly, float frontDistance = -10, float backDistance = 10)
    {
        frontDistance = Mathf.Min(frontDistance, 0);
        backDistance = Mathf.Max(backDistance, 0);

        // convert polygon to triangles
        Triangulator triangulator = new Triangulator(poly);
        int[] tris = triangulator.Triangulate();
        Mesh m = new Mesh();
        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[poly.Length * 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < poly.Length; i++)
        {
            vertices[i].x = poly[i].x;
            vertices[i].y = poly[i].y;
            vertices[i].z = frontDistance; // front vertex
            vertices[i + poly.Length].x = poly[i].x;
            vertices[i + poly.Length].y = poly[i].y;
            vertices[i + poly.Length].z = backDistance;  // back vertex    
        }
        int[] triangles = new int[tris.Length * 2 + poly.Length * 6];
        int count_tris = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tris.Length; i += 3)
        {
            triangles[i] = tris[i];
            triangles[i + 1] = tris[i + 1];
            triangles[i + 2] = tris[i + 2];
        } // front vertices
        count_tris += tris.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < tris.Length; i += 3)
        {
            triangles[count_tris + i] = tris[i + 2] + poly.Length;
            triangles[count_tris + i + 1] = tris[i + 1] + poly.Length;
            triangles[count_tris + i + 2] = tris[i] + poly.Length;
        } // back vertices
        count_tris += tris.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < poly.Length; i++)
        {
            // triangles around the perimeter of the object
            int n = (i + 1) % poly.Length;
            triangles[count_tris] = i;
            triangles[count_tris + 1] = n;
            triangles[count_tris + 2] = i + poly.Length;
            triangles[count_tris + 3] = n;
            triangles[count_tris + 4] = n + poly.Length;
            triangles[count_tris + 5] = i + poly.Length;
            count_tris += 6;
        }
        m.vertices = vertices;
        m.triangles = triangles;
        m.RecalculateNormals();
        m.RecalculateBounds();
        m.Optimize();
        return m;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Source: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Triangulator </remarks>
public class Triangulator
{
    private List<Vector2> m_points = new List<Vector2>();

    public Triangulator(Vector2[] points)
    {
        m_points = new List<Vector2>(points);
    }

    public int[] Triangulate()
    {
        List<int> indices = new List<int>();

        int n = m_points.Count;
        if (n < 3)
            return indices.ToArray();

        int[] V = new int[n];
        if (Area() > 0)
        {
            for (int v = 0; v < n; v++)
                V[v] = v;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int v = 0; v < n; v++)
                V[v] = (n - 1) - v;
        }

        int nv = n;
        int count = 2 * nv;
        for (int m = 0, v = nv - 1; nv > 2;)
        {
            if ((count--) <= 0)
                return indices.ToArray();

            int u = v;
            if (nv <= u)
                u = 0;
            v = u + 1;
            if (nv <= v)
                v = 0;
            int w = v + 1;
            if (nv <= w)
                w = 0;

            if (Snip(u, v, w, nv, V))
            {
                int a, b, c, s, t;
                a = V[u];
                b = V[v];
                c = V[w];
                indices.Add(a);
                indices.Add(b);
                indices.Add(c);
                m++;
                for (s = v, t = v + 1; t < nv; s++, t++)
                    V[s] = V[t];
                nv--;
                count = 2 * nv;
            }
        }

        indices.Reverse();
        return indices.ToArray();
    }

    private float Area()
    {
        int n = m_points.Count;
        float A = 0.0f;
        for (int p = n - 1, q = 0; q < n; p = q++)
        {
            Vector2 pval = m_points[p];
            Vector2 qval = m_points[q];
            A += pval.x * qval.y - qval.x * pval.y;
        }
        return (A * 0.5f);
    }

    private bool Snip(int u, int v, int w, int n, int[] V)
    {
        int p;
        Vector2 A = m_points[V[u]];
        Vector2 B = m_points[V[v]];
        Vector2 C = m_points[V[w]];
        if (Mathf.Epsilon > (((B.x - A.x) * (C.y - A.y)) - ((B.y - A.y) * (C.x - A.x))))
            return false;
        for (p = 0; p < n; p++)
        {
            if ((p == u) || (p == v) || (p == w))
                continue;
            Vector2 P = m_points[V[p]];
            if (InsideTriangle(A, B, C, P))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private bool InsideTriangle(Vector2 A, Vector2 B, Vector2 C, Vector2 P)
    {
        float ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy, apx, apy, bpx, bpy, cpx, cpy;
        float cCROSSap, bCROSScp, aCROSSbp;

        ax = C.x - B.x; ay = C.y - B.y;
        bx = A.x - C.x; by = A.y - C.y;
        cx = B.x - A.x; cy = B.y - A.y;
        apx = P.x - A.x; apy = P.y - A.y;
        bpx = P.x - B.x; bpy = P.y - B.y;
        cpx = P.x - C.x; cpy = P.y - C.y;

        aCROSSbp = ax * bpy - ay * bpx;
        cCROSSap = cx * apy - cy * apx;
        bCROSScp = bx * cpy - by * cpx;

        return ((aCROSSbp >= 0.0f) && (bCROSScp >= 0.0f) && (cCROSSap >= 0.0f));
    }
}
```

UPD: Этот скрипт гораздо чувствительнее к polygon colider 2d, относительно прежнего.

Плюс нашёл скрипт для создания границ

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class border : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        DrawPolygonCollider(gameObject.GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>());
    }
    public static void DrawPolygonCollider(PolygonCollider2D collider)
    {
        LineRenderer _lr = collider.gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        _lr.startWidth = 0.025f;
        _lr.endWidth = 0.025f;
        _lr.useWorldSpace = false;
        _lr.positionCount = collider.points.Length - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < collider.points.Length -1; i++)
        {
            _lr.SetPosition(i, new Vector3(collider.points[i].x, collider.points[i].y));
        }
        _lr.SetPosition(collider.points.Length, new Vector3(collider.points[0].x, collider.points[0].y));
    }
}
```

Получилось как-то так:
[image: КАРТА]